# XCode 6.1 UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift

So, I have a game scene. In didMoveToView function I have declared my hold gesture:

```
let holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handle")
view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
```

And "handle" is my function that is called when the user presses and holds the touch:

```
func handle() {
        i++
        println(i)
    }
```

So, i is a global variable and it's 0. The more the user holds the touch the more i will increase. This is what I want to do. My question is: Why should the user to move the finger on the screen in order to increase i instead of holding the finger on the screen without moving it? When I hold the finger, i increases only with 1 when I touch the screen and again with 1 when I lift my finger off the screen. However if I touch the screen and move my finger i will increase. Which is the problem? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not trigger your method every second (or whatever time interval you pretend to) but trigger your method just one time after a specified period of time.

Here is the Apple docs:

> ### UILongPressGestureRecognizer
>
> **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** is a concrete subclass of **UIGestureRecognizer** that looks for long-press gestures. The user must press one or more fingers on a view and hold them there for a
> minimum period of time before the action triggers. While down, the
> user’s fingers may not move more than a specified distance; if they
> move beyond the specified distance, the gesture fails.
>
> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins
> (**UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan**) when the number of allowable
> fingers (**numberOfTouchesRequired**) have been pressed for the
> specified period (**minimumPressDuration**) and the touches do not
> move beyond the allowable range of movement (**allowableMovement**).
> The gesture recognizer transitions to the Change state whenever a
> finger moves, and it ends (**UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded**) when any
> of the fingers are lifted.

[UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uilongpressgesturerecognizer_class/index.html) Class Reference

Comment: I tried with minimumPressDuration and allowableMovement but nothing changes.

Comment: That's because you don't understand how it works. What I'm saying is... There's no way you can do what you want using UILongPressGestureRecognizer, so yo have to look for another way.

Comment: Isn't that a way I could do that through UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Comment: No is not, you should use UILongPressGestureRecognizer to trigger an action after a long press, that's it. Here's an idea, why don't you measure the press duration and then set the ```i``` value with that number?

Comment: Thanks, I'll ty that. With NSTimer, isn't it?